# How to put an image at bottom of TextView row in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, wear-os

I'm working on a layout for WearOS and I am having trouble.  I have a ListView, and each row (TextView) of the ListView takes up the entire screen.  Now, I want to put an icon on the bottom of of each of the TextViews.  My goal is for it to look like the following: [image]

I currently have everything I want besides getting the icon on each row.  I have imported it, I just don't know how to define the XML.  I tried other StackOverFlow questions, but I couldn't get them to work.  I am also confident in my custom adapter.  It is the layouts that is giving me trouble.  I am new to layouts, so it is definitely my failure to understand them that is giving me trouble.  I tried following tutorials that explain how Android layouts work but I am just not getting them for some reason.

The XML for the ListView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defines the layout for the ListView-->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/goals_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the XML for each row of the ListView is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defines the layout for a row in the ListView-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_row"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to use these layouts, so please try to help me with what I already have.  If you have suggestions on a different way to do what I am trying to do, I am open to suggestions but this is how I am going to implement it.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: why don't you use a single textview with a drawable property in your row item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defines the layout for a row in the ListView-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goal_row"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello W"
    android:layout_above="@id/base"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_above="@id/base"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:-------

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:orientation="horizontal"` will place the views side by side, where as `android:orientation="vertical"` will place them vertically, one below another.

Simply change `LinearLayout` in XML for each row of the `ListView` as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_row"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using orientation as **`"horizontal"`** what it does is it will put your widgets side by sides and causing the overlaps change it to **`"vertical"`** and you are ready to go:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defines the layout for a row in the ListView-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_row"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use a single `textview` and put it's drawable as a `bottom`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defines the layout for a row in the ListView-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_row"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```